# not working UISplitViewController - WillHideViewController not called in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I have problem with `UISplitviewcontroller`,

When I create `splitviewcontroller` (first time) shows barbutton and it works fine,

After select table row in master, its remove `detailview1` & add `detailview2`, now the barbutton not shown. if i rotate iPad barbutton will shown,

I don't know why initially not show the bar button. I set delegate, even its not shown the barbutton.

This is the code I used :

```
        UINavigationController navMaster = appDel.SplitView.ViewControllers [0] as UINavigationController;

        if (indexPath.Row == 0) 
        {  
            ViewController1 View1 = new ViewController1 ();
            UINavigationController nav1 = new UINavigationController (View1); 
            appDel.SplitView.WeakDelegate = View1;              
            appDel.SplitView.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{ navMaster, nav1 }; 
        }  
        else if (indexPath.Row == 1) 
        {
            ViewController2 View2 = new ViewController2 ();
            UINavigationController nav2 = new UINavigationController (View2); 
            appDel.SplitView.WeakDelegate = View2;              
            appDel.SplitView.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{ navMaster, nav2 }; 
        }
```

This is the delegate set in `detailviewcontroller1` and `detailviewcontroller2`.

```
[Export("splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:")]
        public void WillHideViewController (UISplitViewController splitController, UIViewController viewController, UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem, UIPopoverController popoverController)
        {
            barButtonItem.Title = "Inputs";
            NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (barButtonItem, true);
            masterPopoverController = popoverController;
        }

    [Export("splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:")]
    public void WillShowViewController (UISplitViewController svc, UIViewController vc, UIBarButtonItem button)
    {
        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (null, true);
        masterPopoverController = null;
    }
```

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2):

`WillHideViewController` will not be called in your example because you set the `WeakDelegate` property prior to showing the new controller. If you switched the order of those two statements, you'd have a similar problem, and `WillShowViewController` would not be called.

Is there a way you can handle the split view delegate from a single class? Generally I handle this delegate in a subclass of `UISplitViewController` and only set `WeakDelegate` once.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. I create delegate and set to UISplitViewController, still I'm not getting barbutton also before I get barbutton if i rotate iPad, now after rotate it not shown barbutton. I Think delegate not set correctly. can you have any delegate sample